# JavaScript Count Duplicate Letter Recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion, count, letter

I face a problem while coding. I want to count how many letters in a word repeat recursively. My code looks like this :

```
var check = words[0]

  if(!words){
     return 0
  } else {
     for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(words[i] == check){
           return 1 //+ countDuplicate (words.slice(1))
        }
     }
     return countDuplicate (words.slice(1))
  }
```

example for test case :

```
countDuplicate ('greatestme') // 2, ==> which are 'e' 3 times and 't' 2 times
```

Comment: If you want to do it recursively, what does the loop do there?

Comment: I'm not so sure. It's just to help me. Is there any way not to use loop ? Pure using recursive method ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you actually want to do. Can you lay out in words the algorithm that you have in mind? Then I might be able to help you write it in either recursive or iterative fashion.

Comment: I want to cout how many a letter repeat itself in a word. For an example : good, letter o repeat 1 time so the answer  is 1. Another example : greatest, e and t repeat. So the answer is 2

Comment: Why do you want to do this with recursion? It is not really a problem that is that well suited for recursion. It is possible, but looks clumsy really.

Comment: I am a student Sir, I need to learn any code method just in case its needed

Comment: OK, I think I get now what you want the result to be. But how do you plan to compute the answer?

Comment: recursive method ? I can code this if I use loop

Comment: @AndyWarhol Please [edit] your question to show the loop solution, then I can help you transform that into a recursive solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/* Method 1 */
function countDuplicate1(word) {
  var arr = word.split("").reduce((acc, cv) => {
    if(!acc[cv]) {
      acc[cv] = 1;
    } else {
      acc[cv]++;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(arr).filter(val => val >1).length;
}

/* Method 2 */
function countDuplicate2(word) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i=0; i< word.length; i++) {
    var chr = word[i];
    for(var j=i+1; j< word.length; j++) {
      if((word[j] == chr) && !arr.includes(word[j])) {
        arr.push(word[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.length;
}
var count1 = countDuplicate1('greatestme');
var count2 = countDuplicate2('greatestme');
console.log(count1);
console.log(count2);
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way don't use object or built-in function?

Comment: @AndyWarhol, why do you ask to not use built-in functions, when you use them yourself? (`slice`). You also use objects yourself... JavaScript is all about objects anyway.

Comment: Thanks again, it works. Mind helping me without map ? I haven't learned it

Answer (score 1):

```js
const freqDist = ([first, ...rest], counts = {}) => (result => (
  rest.length ? freqDist(rest, result) : result
))({ ...counts, [first]: ((counts[first] || 0) + 1) })

/* More readable alternative with mutable `counts` */
// const freqDist = ([first, ...rest], counts = {}) => {
//   counts[first] = (counts[first] || 0) + 1
//   return (rest.length > 0) ? freqDist(rest, counts) : counts
// }

const stripSingles = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => (
  (obj[curr] > 1) ? { ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] } : acc
), {})

console.log(stripSingles(freqDist('greatestme')))
```

Comment: I don't blame you. I did push that ES6 code sugar a bit far. I'll try to explain. freqDist just counts how many times first letter occurs and stores it in counts. Then it passes counts and the rest of the string to itself until there is no rest left. stripSingles simply remove records of any character occurring only once.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not really a good candidate for recursion, but one way to do it is to maintain two sets:

- the set of characters that have only occurred once
- the set of characters that have occurred more than once

While processing the next character you need to decide how these two sets need to be modified. When all characters are processed you return the size of the second set.

Both sets are initalised as empty sets:

```js
function countDuplicate(word, once = new Set, more = new Set) {
    var check = word[0];
    if (!check) return more.size;
    if (once.delete(check)) { // If successful, it was present
        more.add(check);
    } else {
        once.add(check);
    }
    return countDuplicate(word.slice(1), once, more);
}

const result = countDuplicate ('greatestme');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sir can I user paramter which are  one and more inside function not as parameters ?